# Error while executing do_rootfs command using yocto build

Tags: yocto, qemu, glibc

I am trying to integrate the third-party shared libraries into my build for QEMUx86-64 using yocto.

**third-party.bb**

```
LICENSE = "COM"
SECTION = "devel"

FILES_${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/cmake/"
DEPENDS += " glibc "

FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"


THIRD_PARTY_LIB = "${THISDIR}/../thirdparty/lib"


do_install() {

    mkdir -p ${D}/usr/lib
    cp -R ${THIRD_PARTY_LIB}/* ${D}/
}
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev = ""

do_package_qa() {
}
```

I can able to install the libraries and link them successfully. But now the problem is whiling executing the `do_rootfs` command I am getting below error.

```
Error: 
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25) needed by memstack-1.0-r0.core2_64
 Problem 2: package mem-manager-1.0-r1.core2_64 requires libmemstack.so.0.1()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25) needed by memstack-1.0-r0.core2_64
```

I added the DEPENDS on `glibc` in the respective `third-party.bb` file. But I am facing the same error, am I missing something here?

Comment: My first comment is that you need to use `SRC_URI` for best practices, so that the source files are related to your recipe.

Comment: @BelHadjSalemTALEL, Actually I created this `.bb` file just to install the library into the image.

Comment: try to remove `glibc` from DEPENDS, you should be able to install the lib directly without any dependencies

Comment: yes, I tried without DEPENDS on `glibc` but still, the issue is the same.

Comment: The error message is not related to third-party recipe, does the error remain if you remove the recipe entirely ?

Comment: Actually, I already Integrated third part libraries. This is the new version of the libraries while integrating this I am getting the above error. The previous library is working fine.